# Tkinter, how to set state of some elements depending of checkbox status

Tags: python, tkinter

I have variable `pliki` which is from checkbox

```
pliki = IntVar()
plikiC = Checkbutton(secunderFrame, text="Twórz pliki",
                     font=("Bookman Old Style", 8, 'bold'),
                     variable=pliki, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)

if pliki.get() == 1:
    liczba_pE['state'] = NORMAL
    nazwa_pE['state'] = NORMAL
    tresc_pE['state'] = NORMAL

if pliki.get() == 0:
    liczba_pE['state'] = DISABLED
    nazwa_pE['state'] = DISABLED
    tresc_pE['state'] = DISABLED
```

This code don't work as I had meant to work.
I want if checkbox is checked set state of some elements to NORMAL but when not checked set to DISABLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar with a `RadioButton()` by linking the command to a function that hides it:

```
v = tk.IntVar()
tk.Radiobutton(self.widget, text="Turn on", variable=v, value=1, command=self.show_other_widget).grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Radiobutton(self.widget, text="Turn off", variable=v, value=2, command=self.hide_other_widget).grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Which links to:

```
def hide_other_widget(self):
    self.other_widget.configure(state='disabled')

def show_other_widget(self):
    self.other_widget.configure(state='normal')
```

I don't think you can do this with a single Checkbutton though because the command is only run when it is turned on and not when it is turned off (As described at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm). You could instead use a thread to continually check the button status and adjust your widget accordingly though!

```
import threading

def check_button_status():
    while True:
        status = pliki.get()
        if status == 1:
            liczba_pE['state'] = NORMAL
            nazwa_pE['state'] = NORMAL
            tresc_pE['state'] = NORMAL
        else:
            liczba_pE['state'] = DISABLED
            nazwa_pE['state'] = DISABLED
            tresc_pE['state'] = DISABLED

pliki = IntVar()
plikiC = Checkbutton(secunderFrame, text="Twórz pliki",
                     font=("Bookman Old Style", 8, 'bold'),
                     variable=pliki, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
t = threading.Thread(target=check_button_status) # make our thread
t.start() # have it monitor the button status forever
```

Comment: I still don't know how to use it hah

Comment: I understand what you had wrtitten but don't know how to implement it to my problem

Comment: I think it will be better if it be checkbutton. One button instead of two looks simpler for what I need to do